# php-mail function returns false but still sent mail

Tags: php, email

php mail function is returning false but still mails are being sent.

I have tried to sent mail using correct BCC, it sends the mail and return true.
But in case of wrong BCC mail is being sent but return value(mail();) is false.

```
<?php


$to = "xyz@test.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$bcc = "xyz"; //tried giving wrong bcc
// More headers
$headers .= 'From: XYZ<xyz@test.com>' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$bcc .  "\r\n";

if(mail($to,"subject","mail_body",$headers))
echo "Sent";    
else
{
echo "failed";
print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Comment: is your server configured to be an SMTP server?

Comment: Hi @Ritesh, From php docs "Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise." In case of wrong BCC, it cannot deliver the email to BCC account so returns False;

Comment: @SaroshKhatana but mail is being received by the receiver(to part)

Comment: @treyBake not sure, but sendmail is there in php.ini file